# Плавное изменение прозрачности при прокрутке

Tags: jquery, css3, javascript, opacity, веб-программирование

Сделал для сайта кнопку "наверх", и хочу что бы она плавно появлялась при прокрутке страницы вниз (как в ВК), но что бы её прозрачность зависела он расстояния прокрутки.
Получился такой код:

```js
var h = window.outerHeight,
    t = window.innerHeight,
    r = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  r = $(window).scrollTop() - t;
  if (r > getDocumentHeight() - 200) {
    $('#ToTop').css({
      opacity: 1
    });
    $('#ToTop').css({
      display: 'block'
    });
  }
  if (r > 0) {
    var op = r / 1000;
    $('#ToTop').css({
      opacity: op
    });
    $('#ToTop').css({
      display: 'block'
    });
  } else $('#ToTop').css({
    display: 'none'
  });
});
```

Но проблема в том, что цифры прозрачности в CSS то меняются, а вот сама кнопка изменяется только при остановке прокрутки страницы.
На пример кнопка "Вверх" в вк меняет прозрачность именно в процессе прокрутки.
Подскажите как такое можно реализовать.

Comment: а что не работает ? у меня почему-то все работает http://jsfiddle.net/Y3538/ и даже так http://jsfiddle.net/Y3538/1/.

Answer (score 4):

```js
var wnd = $(window),
    opacityControl = $('div');

wnd.scroll(function(){
    var top = wnd.scrollTop(),
        opacity = top > 500 ? 1 : top * 2 / 1000;
   
    opacityControl.css('opacity', opacity);
});
```

```css
div{
    opacity:0;
    height:1500px;
    background:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    opacity block
</div>
```

Comment: не плохо-бы было,что-бы вы сначало узнали высоту страницы а потом отняли высоту экрана,потом,прокрученое разделили-бы на на чило выше,получили-бы соотношение в процентах,которое поставили-бы в opacity